# In Multi Threading how getId Method decide ID for any thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread.currentThread().getId() return thread Id in long but how thread id is decided by compiler. also there is any way set id for particular Thread .because there is no method like setId

Comment: Maybe there is no `setId` because I would not trust a programmer to set it.  Why would you want a programmer to set it?  You can however set the name.

Comment: why you need to set thread ID? what are you trying to achieve? What has compiler to do with ThreadID? It's incremented every time you create new Thread at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java 8  the thread IDs are handed out sequentially on construction of the thread (taken from the implementation of `Thread`):

```
private static synchronized long nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}
```

As the API documentation of `Thread.getId()` states, the ID is promised to be unique and constant during it's lifetime:

> Returns the identifier of this Thread.  The thread ID is a positive
>    long number generated when this thread was created.
>    The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime.
>    When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

So changing the thread ID is not possible and allowing to change the ID would violate this.